# Installing sensu, sensu-dashboard does not install

Tags: installation, docker, ubuntu-14.04, sensu

I am installing a sensu server inside a docker container running ubuntu 14.04 but when I install it for some reason it does not install the sensu-dashboard.

When I run the following command to set up the defaults I get a file does not exist error

**> Command: update-rc.d sensu-dashboard defaults**

> **Error: update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/sensu-dashboard: file does not exist**

I have searched for the file but does not seem to be installed anywhere.

Has anyone else had this problem before when installing sensu or know how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you running this command through Docker entrypoint?

Comment: No, my entry command is /bin/bash and I am treating it like a normal server when installing sensu. I have tried installing it on a regular sever without docker and am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Even i'm facing the same issue.I'm trying to install on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I decided to just install another dashboard called uchiwa
`apt-get update`
`apt-get install uchiwa`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default Dashboard was removed on July 28th so you missed it by a day!! :( You now have to use a different dashboard. Uchiwa is a great choice and is under very heavy development, so I am sure it will continue to become more feature rich.

[link to uchiwa's github page](https://github.com/sensu/uchiwa)

Answer (score 1):

The default Dashboard was removed that is true but if want to use sensu-dashboard then go for Sensu-Enterprise. 
Here is the link: http://sensuapp.org/enterprise